# Hash value MD5 and SHA256 of file is coming different when file is from system32 folder. Why?

Tags: hash, cryptography, window, group-policy

I calculated MD5 and SHA256 hash values of notepad.exe and mspaint.exe through online hash generators [md5FileCalculator](https://md5file.com/calculator)  [Onlinemd5](http://onlinemd5.com/).
What i noticed is that if i calculate when both exe's are present in their actual postion in system32 the value coming is different than when placed somewhere out of system32 folder.
What is the reason behind that ? Which is the correct hash value ?

I am using Software Restriction policy to block the applications, I created a hash rule for notepad.exe(present in SYSTE32 folder) file and blocked it. When I check the hash value in registry it is different from the hash value  of notepad.exe (from  SYSTEM32 folder) calculated through other methods like online md5 calculators or through Windows API. But when I copy the notepad.exe file into some other folder say on desktop and calculate the hash value, it is coming same as it is in registry for which I created the rule.So the correct value is I think the one which I get when file is out of system32 folder. But I am not getting why it is happening ? Does it have something to do with permissions ?

Comment: can you please re-check your question? I've done what you've suggested and i still got the same hash values

Comment: notepad.exe file present in C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe 
File Version : 6.1.7600.16385
File Size : 193536 bytes
Hash Value(MD5) : d378bffb70923139d6a4f546864aa61c

Notepad.exe(i copied the file to desktop) C:\Users\User_name\desktop\notepad.exe
File Version : 6.1.7600.16385
File Size : 193536 bytes
Hash Value(MD5) : f2c7bb8acc97f92e987a2d4087d021b1

Used MD5file.com for generating the hash values

Comment: @ArturPeniche How you are calculating the hash Value ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of 32-bit applications running on 64-bit Windows, and how Windows handles the System32 folder for those programs.

This was also driving me nuts for a while because I couldn't for the life of me figure out why certain files in System32 (namely .dlls and .exes) were returning different hashes depending on what I checked them with.

Using [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) and Firefox to upload a file to check its hash, I got different results compared to using [QTTabBar](http://qttabbar.sourceforge.net/)'s hash checker, which runs inside explorer.exe.

But if I copied one of these files to another location, I would then get identical results across all programs.

Meanwhile, HxD showed different file lengths for the copied file vs the one in System32, and while both showed similar byte distribution, there were also significant differences.

But then I thought to try the same thing on another folder, and finally cracked it, with a little help from [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64)

> The operating system uses the **%SystemRoot%\System32** directory for its
> 64-bit library and executable files. This is done for backward
> compatibility reasons, as many legacy applications are hardcoded to
> use that path. When executing 32-bit applications, WoW64 transparently
> redirects 32-bit DLLs to **%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64**, which contains 32-bit
> libraries and executables.
>
> 32-bit applications are generally not aware
> that they are running on a 64-bit operating system. 32-bit
> applications can access **%SystemRoot%\System32** through the pseudo
> directory **%SystemRoot%\Sysnative**.

Because HxD and Firefox (and most other browsers) are all 32-bit applications, when you load a file into them, Windows is actually transparently redirecting them to the file of the same name in the SysWOW64 folder (presumably if you ran a 64-bit browser, you would not encounter this problem).

Similarly, when you copy a file out of System32 to another location, explorer.exe, being a 64-bit process, copies the original System32 file, and not the (confusingly named) SysWOW64 equivalent.

So as the wiki states, if you enter `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative`
into the path of the open file dialogue in your 32-bit application, it should load the file from the **real** System32 folder, and give you the correct result.

And if you check the files in the SysWOW64 directory, all files should return the same respective hashes regardless of what you open them with.

Further reading:

- [SysWOW64](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/32-64-bit-windows-folder-x86-syswow64.htm)
- [Sysnative](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/sysnative-folder-64-bit-windows.htm)

Comment: I copied the notepad.exe from Sys32 to desktop. Then I checked the hashes for:
System32, SysWow64 and Desktop. Sys32 and Wow 64 were identical whereas the file on the Desktop was different...

Comment: What did you check the hashes with? If you used a 32 bit application, when you check the System32 file it will return the same result as SysWow64 (because Windows is redirecting it there) but by copying it to your desktop, the 64 bit explorer.exe is creating a copy of the original file from System32, so you'll get the different result. Try loading the notepad.exe using %SystemRoot%\sysnative and see what happens

Comment: Just to support the answer, I write a program called QuickHash that I compile only as a 32-bit program and it runs fine on both 64-bit and 32-bit systems. However, a user reported that files in C:\Windows\System32 was reporting incorrect hashes. I verified the report and found it to be correct. Yet, if the file(s) are copied to c:\temp, they hash just fine. So I need to look at compiling 32\64bit versions from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're checking the exact same file yet on diferent paths? I think you're checking two diferent notepad.exe. Check the size of the file... it must be exacly the same on bytes. 
I've just checked my **notepad.exe** on two distinct paths **C:\Windows\System32** and **C:\Windows** and they are diferent.

Comment: I copied the file from system32 folder to desktop. Size showing is same for both file.